# LINQ equivalent of f#'s builder.Zero()?

Tags: c#, f#, monoids

So, I've become quite addicted to f#'s computation expressions and custom builders. I have to use c# for most of my daily work but still want to use LINQ expressions with my own monads/monoids.  Does anybody know if there's a c# analog to f#'s `Zero` method?

[Relevant f# docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions)

Here's what I do in f#:

```ml
type OptionBuilder() =
    member x.Bind(v,f) = Option.bind f v
    member x.Return v = Some v
    member x.ReturnFrom o = o
    member x.Zero() = Option.None

let option = OptionBuilder()

// Example usage (I want something similar from c#)

let t : Option<int> =
    option { if false then return 5 }
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here but I'll give it a shot. Consider clarifying the question.

The equivalent in C# to an `if` with no `else` in a monadic workflow is:

```
from a in b
where c(a)
select a
```

*Logically* this is equivalent to (using your Bind, Return and Zero)

```
Bind(b, a => c(a) ? Return(a) : Zero)
```

But C# does not lower a where clause into a SelectMany (which is what C# calls Bind). C# lowers a Where clause in a query comprehension to a call to

```
Where(M<T>, Func<T, bool>)
```

In short: C# has arbitrary monadic workflows in the form of query comprehensions; any monadic type with the Select, SelectMany, Where, etc, methods can be used in a comprehension. But it doesn't really generalize to additive monads with an explicit zero. Rather, "Where" is expected to have the semantics of the bind operation I noted above: it should have the same effect as binding a single value onto the end if the item matches the predicate, and the zero value if not.

Plainly "Where" for sequences does that.  If you have [a, b, c] and want to filter out b, that's the same as concatenating together [[a], [], [c]]. But of course it would be crazily inefficient to actually build and concatenate all those little sequences. The *effect* has to be the same, but the actual operations can be much more efficient.

C# is really designed to have support for very specific monads: the sequence monad via `yield` and query comprehensions, the continuation comonad via `await`, and so on. We didn't design it to enable arbitrary monadic workflows as you see in Haskell.

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Alongside Eric's excellent answer, here's some code:

```
        var result =
        from value in Option.Some(5)
        where false
        select value;
```

C#'s LINQ comprehension looks for the corresponding extension method, `Where`. Here's an example implementation:

```
   public static Option<T> Where<T>(this Option<T> option, Func<T, bool> condition)
        {
            if(option is None || !condition(option.Value))
                return None;

            return option;
        }
```

The `Where` itself has to define the *zero* case.

Comment: Indeed, `where false` must have the semantics that the result is the zero monad. That's a nice insight. From this we can see things like: the zero of the `IObservable<T>` monad must be the observable sequence that *never* calls `OnNext`. So, a small puzzle: what is the zero of `Task<T>`?

Comment: Since it cannot be allowed to logically return a result, there's only one choice: `Task.FromCanceled(new CancellationToken(true))`

Comment: That's a reasonable choice but not the only one; other possibilities are another task that has an exception completion, or a task that runs forever and never completes.

Comment: That's interesting. Is there a stronger case for one over the other in a theoretical sense, or is it simply what behavior is desired in the implementation?

Comment: Running forever or producing an exception are in some sense both a kind of side effect. Put another way: running forever is useless/rude, and not every language supports exceptions as a control flow. In a world of pure functional programming we might simply say that `Task<T>` is not an additive monad to begin with, so it need not have a zero. (And in fact `Task<T>` is perhaps better characterized as a comonad.)